# pytest parameterize - row from CSV as a testcase

Tags: python, rows, pytest, parameterized-tests

I have to read a CSV file and for each combination in each row need to run some methods.I would like to see each row as a test case. Is it possible to send row as a param - pytest parameterize my test case? Can you please give me some idea on how to do that?

Here is the pseudo code:

```
class test_mytest:
  def test_rows:
    for row in csvreader:
       run_method(row)
       for onecol in row:
          run_method2(onecol)
```

I have tried reading the `pytest` documentation but it was not clear for me.

Here is what I am doing for using generate_tests hook for row as a param.I would like to know how to do same for the inner for loop function-this inner loop also should be collected as a test case

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    read_csvrows()
    for funcargs in metafunc.cls.params[metafunc.function.__name__]:
        # schedule a new test function run with applied **funcargs
        metafunc.addcall(funcargs=funcargs)

class TestClass:

    params = {
       'test_rows': rows,   
    }
    def test_rows:
        run_method(row)
        for onecol in row:
             test_method2(onecol)
```

Now, I need to generate reports for the -for loop calling test_method2 (it is parameterized method for list of elements in the column in each row of csv file).  Pytest needs to collect those as test case as well.

Appreciate your help.Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will probably want to use the `pytest_generate_tests()` hook as described here: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/parametrize.html#pytest-generate-tests  This allows you to read the csv file and parametrize the tests you want based on it's contents.

**Update**:

The updated question seems not entirely clear, but I'm assuming you need to test something on a row as well as on a column.  This simply asks for two tests:

```
def test_row(row):
    assert row  # or whatever

def test_column(col):
    assert col  # or whatever
```

Now all that remains is to create the parametrized fixtures for `row` and `col` using the `pytest_generate_tests()` hook.  So in the `conftest.py` file:

```
def test_generate_tests(metafunc):
    rows = read_csvrows()
    if 'row' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        metafunc.parametrize('row', rows)
    if 'col' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        metafunc.parametrize('col', list(itertools.chain(*rows)))
```

Notice the use of the recommended `metafunc.parametrize()` function instead of the deprecated `metafunc.addcall()`

Comment: Hey Thanks for reply.I read that link before and tried pytest_generate_tests() hook.Had some issues but now resolved. This link helped me most to understand http://holgerkrekel.net/2009/05/13/parametrizing-python-tests-generalized/

Comment: Now for generating reports I need to make the inner for loop also look like a test case. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you update the question with the actual `pytest_generate_tests()` code and maybe show one or two test functions which are parametrised with it?  Otherwise it's hard to just guess what you mean.

Comment: Hi flub, I updated the question.Can you pl help me with this requirement.I tried with parametrize marker and also tried with @params. One more quick info is that for the second function I am using in python greenlets